# When I try to decompose a double number into an array as elements, why do I get an offset preventing me from getting the last digit?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, numbers, number-formatting

[image: output bug on iteration starting order]

I have a problem. **I want from a given number to get each digit as an element in the same array**.

But when I compile, if I extend the range from one iteration above the size of the given number, I get a corrupted data exception from Visual Studio in Debug mode as an exception.

I thought first that was because the int type is only 4 digit max length as a 4 bytes entity because I used to get only one digit for greater number above 9999. But I noticed that my number starts at an iteration value one too late...which makes it impossible to show the last digit.

If I add a zero to my given number, I can manually offset in the opposite direction, but that doesn't work with my original number.

But, I can't find out how to fix that...Here is my code.
Before asking for help, here is a screenshot explaining the principle which is used to convert the number into an array: [math theory formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qloQ4.jpg)
I wish to solve it with the number type only because the char type involves another way managing the memory with buffers...which I don't really know how to handle right know.

Can someone help me to complete the debugging please ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

//method to convert user number entry to array of digits
long long numToArray(double num,double arrDigits[], const long long n) {
    //instanciate variables

        //array of with m elements
    arrDigits[n];
    double* loopValue = new double(0);

    //extract the digits and store them into arrDigits array
    for (long long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        long temp = 0;
        for (long k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
            //mathematical general formula
            temp += arrDigits[i - k] * pow(10, k);
            loopValue = new double(0);
            *loopValue = floor(num / pow(10, n - i)) - temp;
            arrDigits[i] = *loopValue;
        }
        std::cout << "digits array value at " << i << " is " << arrDigits[i] << " \n";
    }
    return 0;
}
//main program interacting with the user
int main()
{
    std::cout << "please type an integer: ";
    double num;
    const long long n = sizeof(num);
    double array[n]{};
    std::cin >> num;
    //call the method to test if all values are in the array
    numToArray(num, array, n);
    return 0;
}
```

[Explaining the troubleshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dFQS.png)

Note : Visual Studio shows error if I extend from n to n+1. If I let the type int or long, sizeof(num) is all the time 4...
Then, I had to set it as double and to extract it from the main scope, which makes it ...double...
People asking to remove pointer, it is impossible to run the program if I do so.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221757/discussion-on-question-by-z0t-lod-when-i-try-to-decompose-a-double-number-into-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally encapsulated the whole code into two functions. But I have an extra value at first and last iteration...

The answer is almost complete, just need to solve the offset from inside the main moved to it's owned function. I finally added a new array variable with the exact size I want from the two new functions, so we get the array which will be possible to manipulate so far away.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <list>

int CountNumberDigits(int num) {
    int count = 0;
    long long CountingNum = static_cast<long long>(num);
    while (CountingNum != 0) {
        CountingNum = CountingNum / 10;
        ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

double* NumToArray(double num) {
    double converternum = num * 10;//removing the right offset to keep the last digit
    const int containerSize = sizeof(double); //defining array constant size
    int sizeRescale = containerSize - CountNumberDigits(num);//set general offset to handle according to the user entry
    double arrDigits[containerSize] = {};//initialize array with a sufficient size.
    double* loopValue = new double(0); //define pointer variable to make to operation possible

    //extract the digits and store them into arrDigits array
    for (long long i = 0; i < containerSize; i++) {
        long temp = 0;
        for (long k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
            //mathematical general formula adapted to the computation
            temp += arrDigits[i - k] * pow(10, k);
            loopValue = new double(0); //reinitialize the pointer
            *loopValue = floor(converternum / pow(10, containerSize - i)) - temp; //assign the math formula to the pointer
            arrDigits[i] = *loopValue;//assigne the formula for any i to the array relatively to k
        }
    }

    //convert array to a list
    std::list<double> listDigits(std::begin(arrDigits), std::end(arrDigits));
    for (double j : listDigits) {
        std::cout << j << " ";
    }

    //remove the zeros offset and resize the new converted list
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeRescale; j++) {
        listDigits.pop_front();
    }
    //convert list to array
    double* arrOutput = new double[listDigits.size()]{};
    std::copy(listDigits.begin(), listDigits.end(), arrOutput);
    double* ptrResult = arrOutput;
    return ptrResult;
}

int main()
{
    //Entry request of any natural integer within the range of double type
    std::cout << "Please type a natural integer from 1 to 99999999\n";
    double num;
    std::cin >> num;
    int count = CountNumberDigits(num);
    std::cout << "number of digits compositing your natural integer: " << count << std::endl;

    double* ptrOutput = NumToArray(num);
    //reduce the array to the num size
    double* shrinkArray = new double[CountNumberDigits(num)];
    for (int i = 0; i < CountNumberDigits(num); i++) {
        *(shrinkArray+i) = ptrOutput[i];
        std::cout << *(shrinkArray+i) << " ";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want from a given number to get each digit as an element in the same array.

If you want to simply get each number into an array, it takes only a few lines of code to convert the decimal to a string, remove the decimal point (if it exists), and then copy the string to a buffer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    double d = 1.45624234;
    
    std::ostringstream strm;
    strm << std::setprecision(12);

    // copy this to a string using the output stream
    strm << d;
    std::string s = strm.str();

    // remove the decimal point
    s.erase(std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '.'), s.end());

    // Now copy each digit to a buffer (in this case, vector)
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(v), [&](char ch) { return ch - '0';});

    // output the results
    for (auto c : v )
      std::cout << c;
}
```

Output:

```
145624234
```

All of the work you were doing is already done for you by the standard library.  In this case the overloaded `operator <<` for `double` when streamed to a buffer creates the string.  How it does it?  That is basically what your code is attempting to do, but obviously safely and correctly.

Then it's just a matter of transforming each digit character into an actual integer that represents that digit, and that is what `std::transform` does.  Each digit character is copied to the vector by subtracting the character `0` from each char digit.

Comment: Ok, but the strcpy_s require char pointer...Is it bad to talk about pointer on stackoverflow ? Sorry, i need to ask this question, because the buffer size is now essential to make run a console application...It may be confusing, but the transform parse the string into char inside a vector, right ?
Which means in the end you have char numbers you display in the end, which type is...string again that can be looped.

But your solution is ambiguous compared to this one here: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/

In 2020, that should be fine to use the new features.

Comment: The code.you linked to does not convert the string into an array of digits.  It converts to a string, but doesn't do the step I illustrated of then taking that string and turning it into an array of digits.  Also, the site you linked to is notorious for bad code samples, just to let you know.

Comment: What is unclear with the char, is that for any entry number, you may be exposed to an unsafe situation where the size of your buffer is unknown.

I use the inbuilt sizeof function to get the number of digits. This is not the only way to get it, but the new C++ standards requests const buffer size to make it safe.
strcpy_s makes it possible to convert string to char.
Then, you show an example for small numbers. But, the problem is not the size, it is the iteration offset which kicks out one digit of the number out of range entailing corrupted data error when looping up to n+1 instead of n.

Comment: The code doesn't care how big the buffer is.  The buffer is automatically resized for each digit.  That is what the `std::back_inserter` does.

Comment: I asked for any natural integer... He set the value as a string float...The buffer is about the max size of the number you enter in strings.
Check the last answer, I corrected everything to make it understandable. When you want to convert string to char, you have to set a const char buffer size, which he hasn't done in his code. Moreover, I don't know about that many libraries. What are their uses in the end ? I just implemented a single mathematic formula, people comment anything on the newcomers contribution...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <list>

int main()
{
    //Entry request of any natural integer within the range of double type
        std::cout << "Please type a natural integer from 1 to 99999999\n";
        double num;
        std::cin >> num;

        //counting the number of digits
        int count = 0;
        long long CountingNum = static_cast<long long>(num);
        while (CountingNum != 0) {
            CountingNum = CountingNum/10;
            ++count;
        }
        std::cout << "number of digits compositing your natural integer: " << count<<std::endl;

        //process the value for conversion to list of digits, so you can
        //access each digits by power and enhance your calculus operations
        double converternum = num * 10;//removing the right offset to keep the last digit
        const int containerSize = sizeof(double); //defining array constant size
        int sizeRescale = containerSize - count;//set general offset to handle according to the user entry
        double arrDigits[containerSize] = {};//initialize array with a sufficient size.
        double* loopValue = new double(0); //define pointer variable to make to operation possible

        //extract the digits and store them into arrDigits array
        for (long long i = 0; i < containerSize; i++) {
            long temp = 0;
            for (long k = 0; k < i + 1; k++) {
                //mathematical general formula adapted to the computation
                temp += arrDigits[i - k] * pow(10, k);
                loopValue = new double(0); //reinitialize the pointer
                *loopValue = floor(converternum / pow(10, containerSize - i)) - temp; //assign the math formula to the pointer
                arrDigits[i] = *loopValue;//assigne the formula for any i to the array relatively to k
            }
            std::cout << "digits array value at " << i << " is " << arrDigits[i] << " \n";
        }
        //convert array to a list
        std::list<double> listDigits(std::begin(arrDigits), std::end(arrDigits));
        //print the converted list
        std::cout << "array converted to list: ";
        for (double j : listDigits) {
            std::cout << j << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        //remove the zeros offset and resize the new converted list
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeRescale; j++) {
            listDigits.pop_front();
        }
        std::cout << "removed zero element to the list\n";
        for (double i : listDigits) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "natural integer successfully converted into list digits data\n";
        return 0;
}
```

[an example on debug mode in Visual Studio 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H61wD.png)

Comment: With this conversion number, you can consider each digit as a single wheel with numbers from 0 to 9. You can access each digit and make faster operations from random values. It requires pointer because I write it from a dice game rule I want to type in C++ for learning purposes. I hope that will help people learning C++ like me...
I understand why people want to convert it from strings, but the standards changed, and neglicting the buffer size issue makes it unsafe, because you have to set the max number to make it safe as well from pointer view access as well as for the buffer size.

Comment: This is my first question on stackoveflow. This is the first mathematic problem I write for a C++ solution project because I need a number special access without counting by unit incrementation....
I was just asking why the compiler is making an offset of my values...but nobody answered. I corrected the bug. But if people find my code too long, they should propose an equivalent respecting the standards for the case of a given natural integer converted to a list of digits since the array cannot be resized after the process...

Comment: My code is stacking with a double type and only 2 additionnal headers to make the job. For a Dice game, I need 5-6 digits... the double type fits to the problem. Indeed, you can get greater number with a large constant buffer pointer but the application field may be conflictual because those list of digits are meaningless for excessive based 10 power values divisor above the 8 digits limit.
"stackoverflow", I don't know what that means, but if I write it with full explaination, that will make it possible for someone to explain why my process suffers from an offset removing the last digit ?

Comment: header stack vs math stack.
Which one to choose ?
In a case of bug, which one is easier to fix ?
Cost of living is not only a matter of time, it is a matter of way doing things. Starting reading a page with a header stack or reading a page starting straight inside ?
People should answer the question. "stackingoverflow" may loose it's meaning throught the evolution to c++ standards if people makes only header stack...